# Can I detect valid JSONP return?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I want to send/receive data to a web service on a different server that does not have CORS enabled. I have to use JSONP to do it. The service requires authentication and most of the time the user is in an SSO environment and the SSO mechnaism easily passes them to the service without issue.

When not inside the SSO environment, the user is redirected (301) to a login page, which of course returns invalid javascript because the file would start with `<!Doctype...`

Is there a way to see if the returned data is operable? I know exactly what the first 15 chars should be anytime the user can successfully access the service. I would like to check the return and then do something like:

```
if(dataIsValid){ //continue normally, build page with returned data }

else{ //redirect to non-SSO login page }
```

Or anything that resembles that kind of a workflow.

Comment: I think the error handler of your jquery ajax call should handle it.

Comment: You can pass your redirect on the error function

Comment: You guys are fast! I tried combinations of the `success`, `error`, and `jsonpCallback` params, but the one I didn't try was using `error` for a fail handler and `jsonpCallback` as the success handler. In my scenario any action resulting in an error is exactly what I need to catch, where the only success I care about is a valid jsonp response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using jQuery since you've added a relevant tag.

```
var dataIsValid = true;
var data = {};
try {
   data= $.parseJSON(data);
} catch (exc){
   dataIsValid = false;
}
//...
```